# Django - ProgrammingError - column does not exist

Tags: django, django-models

I normally find a solution around this problem. I even tried the nuclear option of resetting the data base completely with `python manage.py flush` but no luck. (I have also tried by deleting the migrations folder, but again no result)

the exact error message is the following:

> column main_reviewrating.venue_id does not exist

Maybe it's the first time I pay attention to this but the venue**_id** seems strange.

I am quite sure the usual message would have something like

> main_reviewrating.venue (without the **_id**

When I run `python manage.py showmigrations <your_app_name>` it does show

> [X] 0001_initial

I should also add that I am running this on my local, so no problem specific to deployment.

Here is the code (**models.py**)

```
class Venue(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Name",max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
   
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name) if self.name else ''

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Product Name', max_length=120, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table='Product'
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)

class ReviewRating(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="usercomments")
    product=models.ForeignKey(Product,related_name="comments", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    review =models.TextField(max_length=250)
    rating =models.IntegerField(choices=RATING, default=0)
    venue = models.ForeignKey(Venue, blank=True, null=True, related_name="venues", on_delete=models.CASCADE)


    def __str__(self):
        return '%s - %s'%(self.user, self.product)
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

**Edit**: on a second thought, maybe I am using the ForeignKey wrong. What I am trying to do here is to link a specific review, of a specific product to a specific venue.

This means, the same product could be reviewed by the same user in a different venue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Delete your database like `something.sqlite3` (for backup you may rename it).

2.Delete all migration file except `__init__.py`.

3.Run the migrations command again.

Hopefully you will get no issue.

Comment: I did delete the data base. However, after your second comment I went back to settings.py were I was set up on postgres. I moved everything back to sql3 and this time the migration worked. It's the first time I have this problem. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Delete all files in migration folder except **init**.py file in your app folder and the run makemigrations.

Comment: I did that already. I tried again, just in case, but no luck I am afraid.

Comment: Just to say, it's not me that down voted your answer! (thanks for trying to help!)